# How to pass branch name to build.xml

Tags: teamcity

Say, I have this branch specification: +:refs/heads/* and I want to get branch name in build.xml. Any parameters like ${vcsroot.branch} return string env.branch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to add an Environment Variable called something like `env.branch` then set its value to `%teamcity.build.branch%` then in your `build.xml` you can read it in using something like:

```
<property environment="env"/>
${env.branch}
```

Assuming this is `ant` for the last part.

Answer (score 0):

Branch related parameters are described in TeamCity documentation: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Predefined+Build+Parameters#PredefinedBuildParameters-BranchRelatedParameters