# How to get the branch name which is in being build in teamcity to be stored to a variable in build.xml

Tags: git, ant, teamcity

I have a project configured in teamcity.

I need to know the name of the branch that is being build to be passed to a variable in build.xml. For this I created a separate target in build.xml file and gave it as a build command in the build step.

But still I am not able to get the branch name store in the desired variable in build.xml.

I followed this link [How to pass branch name to build.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045492/how-to-pass-branch-name-to-build-xml)

Still I was unsuccessful.

Can someone help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the steps in your linked other Q/A are correct and should work. add an environment parameter to your teamcity build and assign it the value of %teamcity.build.branch% and then use that environment variable in your ANT script.

Comment: Do i have to create a separate property in build.xml file before using it ? I tried to follow the steps mentioned, but when I tried to print the value, it literally printed "${env.branch}".